# (Vue) Axios set data not working with 2 properties. I can't explain why

Tags: javascript, vue.js, vuejs2, axios, vee-validate

I have the weirdest bug I have ever encountered. I am using Axios and Vee-Validate in my Vue project and from my api I get an error. So withing axios I have a catch.

example:

```
this.$http.post('v1/auth/register', {
                first_name: this.first_name,
                last_name: this.last_name,
                email: this.email,
                phone: this.phone,
                password:this.password
            }).then((response) => {
                this.registration_card = 2;
            }).catch((error) => {

                if(error.data.error.message === "email_already_exists") {
                    let input = this.$refs['email'].$children[0];
                    input.errors.add({ field: 'email', msg: 'email already is use'});
                    this.loading = false;

                    console.log(input.errors);
                    console.log(this.loading);
                }

            });
```

Now here comes the weird part. With this code:

```
let input = this.$refs['email'].$children[0];
    input.errors.add({ field: 'email', msg: 'email already is use'});

this.loading = false;
```

the input.errors is still empty and error wil not be displayed. BUT when i do this:

```
let input = this.$refs['email'].$children[0];
    input.errors.add({ field: 'email', msg: 'email already is use'});

 // this.loading = false;
```

So this.loading will NOT get set, then the error will get set and displayed in my view.

But I want this.loading still be false because I want my loading icon not be displayed. Anyone have a explanation about this.

EDIT: More code

```
methods: {
    register: function () {
        let anyError = false;
        this.$validate(this, ['first_name', 'last_name', 'phone', 'email', 'password'], function (value, last_item) {

            this.loading = true;

            if (value === false) {
                anyError = true;
            }

            if (anyError || !last_item) {
                return;
            }

            this.$http.post('v1/auth/register', {
                first_name: this.first_name,
                last_name: this.last_name,
                email: this.email,
                phone: this.phone,
                password: this.password
            }).then((response) => {
                this.registration_card = 2;
            }).catch((error) => {
                if (error.data.error.message === "email_already_exists") {
                    let input = this.$refs['email'].$children[0];
                    input.errors.add({field: 'email', msg: 'email already is use'});
                    this.loadingTest = false;

                    console.log(input.errors);
                    console.log(this.loadingTest);
                }

            });

        }.bind(this));
    },
}
```

this.$validate does this:

```
export default function(scope, arrayOfValues, callback) {

let total = arrayOfValues.length - 1;
let last_item = false;

arrayOfValues.forEach(function(value, index) {
    let input = scope.$refs[value].$children[0];
    input.$validator.validate().then(value => callback(value, total === index, index));
   });
}
```

I do this because i have custom input components

EDIT: this is where i am using loading:

```
<j-button label="Register" :loading="loading" @click.native="register"/>
```

And button coomponent is:

```
<template>
    <button type="button">
        <span v-if="!loading">{{label}}</span>
        <loading v-if="loading"/>
    </button>
</template>

<script>
import loading from 'vue-loading-spinner/src/components/Circle'

export default {
    name: 'j-button',
    props: [
        'label',
        'loading'
    ],
    components: {
        loading
    }
}
</script>
```

EDIT: Even more code!!!!!

My j-input component

```
<template>
    <div>
        <label v-bind:class="{ 'active': (newValue.length > 0)}">{{label}}</label>
        <input v-bind:class="{ 'error': (errors.has(name))}" type="text" :name="name" v-validate="rules" :placeholder="label" v-model="newValue" v-on:input="updateValue()" ref="input">
        <span v-if="errors.has(name)">{{errors.first(name)}}</span>
    </div>
</template>

<script>
    export default {
        name: 'j-text',
        inject: ['$validator'],
        props: [
            'label',
            'name',
            'rules',
            'value',
        ],
        data() {
            return {
                newValue: ''
            }
        },
        created() {
            this.newValue = this.value;
            this.updateValue();
        },
        methods: {
            updateValue: function () {
                this.$emit('input', this.newValue);
            },
        }
    }
</script>
```

Comment: What does the console.log(this.loading) give you?

Comment: if this.loading = false, then false, else true because it is set true beginning of function

Comment: Can you share your html and the entire vue doc. Have you checked that you don't have a v-if on loading that hides your errors

Comment: @Marcus this is not a html problem. Becasue when i do console.log(input.errors) like in my code. the error array is emty when adding the this.loading = false. When I remove that loading part. Then my error array will get the error item.

Edit: in my view I also have this {{this.errors}}. Same story. Without this.loading = false. I have error items. When this.loading = false set in the axios part. No items in error array.

Comment: Okey, would be nice to see the entire code, are u using watchers for anything

Comment: Done. Dont need html i think. Becasue only thing importand about that is {{this.errors}} I have also added that i am using vee validate.

Comment: @Marcus No watchers, no stuff in created() or mounted() etc. Nothing. Only 1 method atm

Comment: Can you post where you use your loading variable? I can only see assignments in your current code.

Comment: @Josh Updated. I also made a little mistake in the register method. there stood this.loadingTest. It should have bin this.loading. (but my real code was correct)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

So i have found the issue and it is still very strange why. I will make another question for this. Its about my j-button component:

```
<template>
    <button type="button">
        <span v-if="!loading">{{label}}</span>
        <loading v-if="loading"/>
    </button>
</template>

<script>
import loading from 'vue-loading-spinner/src/components/Circle'

export default {
    name: 'jellow-button',
    props: [
        'label',
        'loading'
    ],
    components: {
        loading
    }
}
</script>
```

To fix this weird issue I had to change this:

```
<loading v-if="loading"/>
```

To:

```
<loading v-show="loading"/>
```

If I changed this, then the error will be loaded and the button loading icon will be turned off doing this in my catch:

```
}).catch(error => {
                    if(error.data.error.message === "email_already_exists") {
                        let input = this.$refs['email'].$children[0];
                        input.errors.add({field: 'email', msg: 'email already in use'});
                        this.loading = false;
                    }
                });
```

But again. If I do the v-if instead of the v-show in my button then the error will not be showing. Very strange. I will create another question and I hope I get a answer on that.

Answer (score 0):

This is very simple. Only reference change refreshes Vue view.

When you do this:

```
new Vue({
    data: ['property'],
    method: {
       change() {
           this.property = "yes"; // will get refreshed
       }
    }
});
```

The view gets refreshed (changes are displayed). But when you change the object's field reference (not the object itself) or when you call a method on it, it **won't get refreshed**.

```
 change() {
     this.property.field = "yes"; // won't get refreshed
     this.property.mtehod("yes"); // won't get refreshed
 }
```

Only some certain methods (like `array.push()`) are tweaked by Vue.js to recognize that those methods get view refreshed. If you want to make it work you need to call `this.$forceUpdate()` or use `Vue.set()` to change vales.

So when you add your errors, the view won't get refreshed, only when you change your data property (`loading`) the view recognize that data value changed and refreshed your view.

Please read [Reactivity in Depth](https://v2.vuejs.org/v2/guide/reactivity.html#Change-Detection-Caveats), especially chapter "How Changes Are Tracked". Please see which ways of setting data are reactive and which aren't.

Comment: But when i remove the this.loading = false in the catch. The error will be displayed. In the succes part (.then) i also change this.registartion_card = 2 and also that works.

Comment: If i do just this.loading = false, without adding the error. this,loading is also false and the loading icon will vanish

Comment: short saying. If i use 1 of the 2 changes. it works. But if a want both changes, only the this.loading is triggerd. (no matter what order I put the code in)

Comment: @NielsLucas Can you show us your template and what really `$refs['email'].$children[0]` is?

Comment: Its a custom input component. I have added in my question.